# Basics of compiling binary with no dependencies using gnu toolchain

Tags: c, linux, gnu, sox, gnu-toolchain

I'm trying to make an audio file I create slow down using [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/), and although I can easily compile the source files on the linux machine I use regularly, I need to transfer the binary to another linux machine with limited permissions and memory. I tried to copy the binary from the usr/local/bin folder on my machine to the other one and it could not find function references.

Is there a standard way to compile binaries with no dependencies, and if not, how do I set up the SoX binary so that it sees the correct dependencies when I only have write privileges in a temp folder?

Comment: Google for "static linking", IIRC it's just a matter of adding `-static` to your `LDFLAGS` (assuming you have a project with a standard-ish Makefile).

Comment: Add to the previous: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_25.html

Comment: You can tell the binary where to look for shared libraries by setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. Should be easier than recompiling.

Answer (score 3):

You can compile, adding the `-static` flag to the compilation options in the `Makefile`. But be aware of any differences in `glibc` versions between your two (or more) Linux workstations. You want to make sure that you compile on (or target for) the workstation with the older (or oldest) kernel, or your binary may not work due to dependencies on a newer kernel, which cannot be met by an older installation of Linux. So: basically, compile on your oldest machine for better results.

Comment: I'm not sure that I would recommend statically linking your own program. On my Debian/Sid distributions, I have more than 700 programs and only one is statically linked. At least, I don't recommend statically linking core system libraries like `libc`, `libm`, `libdl` ... I believe that distributions have a package manager for good reasons!

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing you need to generate executables without dependencies is the static version of all libraries this executable will use. Usually, libraries are shares as well, meaning if they need to call another library's functions, they use shared linking. To not get 2nd-grade dependencies you need to compile all required libraries statically.